# Im using tcomb plugin for generating dynamic form in react native

Tags: react-native, react-android, tcomb-form-native

Everything is ok , but my form consists select drop down in that im getting '-' in the first even though i didn't specify , how to remove it (You can see in screenshot)

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qecQr.jpg)

```
 const dForm = t.struct({
    items:t.enums({
      "30":"30",
      "31":"31",
      "32":"32",
      "33":"33",
      "34":"34",
      "35":"35",
      "36":"36",
      "37":"37",
      "38":"38",
      "39":"39"
    },"Items")

      <t.form.Form
          type={dForm}
          ref="mandatory"
      />
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense Done please check

Comment: Why is the screenshot from 40-49 and the struct from 30-39? Are you sure you're looking at the correct one?

Comment: @Ortho Home Defense I have two selects both are same

Answer (score 0):

so I am unable to see if you set the `initialState` in your component but you may want to have on your `componentDidMount` method

```
  getInitialState() {
   return {
     value: {
      "30":"30"
    }
  }
```

and set your state that way.

Comment: When i set the default instead of showing '-' it is showing 30 which is good but when open the select it shows '-' again

Comment: in the options object, set nullOption to false.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.** You can replace null value (-) first option with this code

```
items: {
    label: 'Your Label',
    nullOption: {value:'', text: '- - - Choose Items - - -'},
},
```

**Option 2.** you can set nullOption false